# Getting Debian 8 "Jessie" to run on Windows Virtual PC (Windows 7)?

Tags: windows-7, debian, microsoft-virtual-pc, debian-jessie

I have Windows Virtual PC with a handful of virtual machines. I had one successfully running Debian 5 "Lenny" for a few years but as that is an old, unsupported distribution, I tried to upgrade it (and promptly bricked the VM). I deleted the VM and created a new one and installed Debian 8 Jessie from an ISO downloaded from the Debian website.

Initially when installing Lenny, I used this tutorial: https://wiki.debian.org/MicrosoftVirtualPc2007/lenny

I also found this site: http://www.informatics.buzdo.com/p773-debian-initial-installation.htm which suggests that there isn't much difference between installing Lenny, Squeeze, Wheezy or Jessie on Virtual PC.

The installation seemed to complete without errors but no matter what I try, I cannot get it to boot. (Since then I have re-installed Jessie at least 3 times but still the same problem).

It hangs at "random: nonblocking pool is initialized" and "clocksource tsc is unstable" (even though I set the clocksource to PIT in the grub boot command)

I have pressed "e" at the grub screen to edit the boot command and added the "noreplace-paravirt", "clocksource=pit" parameters as well as

```
 set gfxpayload=1024x7689x16,1024x768
```

before the linux command. Still hangs and I have let it sit for more than 30 minutes. I have tried rebooting, recovery mode, re-installing, googling, etc.

I am just wondering if anyone else has successfully run Jessie on Windows Virtual PC or if it's even possible to do. (If not, I'll have to resort to Lenny but I'd really rather have a more up-to-date desktop to use).

Here are the last few lines of what I see on the screen:

```
[    2.665375] mce: Unable to init device /dev/mcelog (rc: -5)
[    2.667811] Using IPI No-Shortcut mode
[    2.670763] registered taskstats version 1
[    2.678252] rtc_cmos 00:00 setting system clock to 2015-11-25 09:01:53 UTC (1448442113)
[    2.684837] Freeing unused kernel memory: 656K (c166d000 - c1711000)
[    2.687282] Write protecting the kernel text: 4604k
[    2.689249] Write protecting the kernel read-only data: 1452k
[    2.690774] NX-protecting the kernel data: 3588l
[   33.931692] random: nonblocking pool is initialized
[  835.408623] Clocksource tsc unstable (delta = 77342613 ns)
```